# Akka Http and Circe, how to serialize entities wrapped in the tagless final approach (Cats Effect)

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I'm building a toy project to learn Scala 3 and i'm stuck in one problem, first of all i'm following the [tagless-final](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/tagless-final-pattern) approach using cats-effect, the approach is working as expected except for the entity serialization, when i try to create a route using akka-http i have the following problem:

```
def routes: Route = pathPrefix("security") {
(path("auth") & post) {
  entity(as[LoginUserByCredentialsCommand]) {
    (command: LoginUserByCredentialsCommand) =>
      complete {
        login(command)
      }
  }
}}

F[
  Either[com.moralyzr.magickr.security.core.errors.AuthError, 
    com.moralyzr.magickr.security.core.types.TokenType.Token
  ]
]
Required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
where:    F is a type in class SecurityApi with bounds <: [_] =>> Any
```

For what i understood, akka-http does not know how to serialize the F highly-kinded type, by searching a little bit i found the [following solution](https://miklos-martin.github.io/tips/2018/05/25/tagless-final-vs-akka-http-routes.html), it consists of creating an implicit called marshallable to show the akka-http how to serialize the type, however when i implement it i get a StackOverflow error :(

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller
import cats.effect.IO

trait Marshallable[F[_]]:
  def marshaller[A: ToResponseMarshaller]: ToResponseMarshaller[F[A]]

object Marshallable:
  implicit def marshaller[F[_], A : ToResponseMarshaller](implicit M: Marshallable[F]): ToResponseMarshaller[F[A]] =
    M.marshaller

  given ioMarshaller: Marshallable[IO] with
    def marshaller[A: ToResponseMarshaller] = implicitly
```

I'm really stuck right now, does anyone have an idea on how can i fix this problem? The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/moralyzr/magickr)

Edit: This is the login code

For clarity, here are the class that instantiate the security api and the security api itself

```
  object Magickr extends IOApp:

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    val server = for {
      // Actors
      actorsSystem <- ActorsSystemResource[IO]()
      streamMaterializer <- AkkaMaterializerResource[IO](actorsSystem)
      // Configs
      configs <- Resource.eval(MagickrConfigs.makeConfigs[IO]())
      httpConfigs = AkkaHttpConfig[IO](configs)
      databaseConfigs = DatabaseConfig[IO](configs)
      flywayConfigs = FlywayConfig[IO](configs)
      jwtConfig = JwtConfig[IO](configs)
      // Interpreters
      jwtManager = JwtBuilder[IO](jwtConfig)
      authentication = InternalAuthentication[IO](
        passwordValidationAlgebra = new SecurityValidationsInterpreter(),
        jwtManager = jwtManager
      )
      // Database
      _ <- Resource.eval(
        DbMigrations.migrate[IO](flywayConfigs, databaseConfigs)
      )
      transactor <- DatabaseConnection.makeTransactor[IO](databaseConfigs)
      userRepository = UserRepository[IO](transactor)
      // Services
      securityManagement = SecurityManagement[IO](
        findUser = userRepository,
        authentication = authentication
      )
      // Api
      secApi = new SecurityApi[IO](securityManagement)
      routes = pathPrefix("api") {
        secApi.routes()
      }
      akkaHttp <- AkkaHttpResource.makeHttpServer[IO](
        akkaHttpConfig = httpConfigs,
        routes = routes,
        actorSystem = actorsSystem,
        materializer = streamMaterializer
      )
    } yield (actorsSystem)
    return server.useForever
```

And

```
class SecurityApi[F[_]: Async](
    private val securityManagement: SecurityManagement[F]
) extends LoginUserByCredentials[F]
    with SecurityProtocols:

  def routes()(using marshaller: Marshallable[F]): Route = pathPrefix("security") {
    (path("auth") & post) {
      entity(as[LoginUserByCredentialsCommand]) {
        (command: LoginUserByCredentialsCommand) =>
          complete {
            login(command)
          }
      }
    }
  }

override def login(
  command: LoginUserByCredentialsCommand
): F[Either[AuthError, Token]] =
  securityManagement.loginWithCredentials(command = command).value
```

================= EDIT 2 =========================================
With the insight provided by Luis Miguel, it makes a clearer sense that i need to unwrap the IO into a Future at the Marshaller level, something like this:

```
  def ioToResponseMarshaller[A: ToResponseMarshaller](
      M: Marshallable[IO]
  ): ToResponseMarshaller[IO[A]] =
    Marshaller.futureMarshaller.compose(M.entity.unsafeToFuture())
```

However, i have this problem:

```
Found:    cats.effect.unsafe.IORuntime => scala.concurrent.Future[A]
Required: cats.effect.IO[A] => scala.concurrent.Future[A]
```

I think i'm close! Is there a way to unwrap the IO keeping the IO type?

Comment: At some point you have to use a concrete type. Like in the Akka routes. How is your `login` method defined?

Comment: I've edited the question with the login method!

Comment: And how does `secApi` is used in the routes?

Comment: Added! You can see the whole code here: https://github.com/moralyzr/magickr, but mostly, it calls a service that goes to the database, everything is wrapped inside an Cats IO Monad.

Comment: I don't think you can mix `IOApp` with **Akka**, I may be wrong tho but I would expect that your main and routes to be written in plain **Akka** actors using `Futures` and then the routes will call a business layer that will return an `F[_]`, everything behind that layer will use `F[_]`  then the routes will call those by fixing `F[_]` to `IO` and finally they will convert that into a `Future` calling `unsafeToFuture()`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You gave me a really great insight, it makes complete sense, Akka Http can't deal with the IO from Cats, so what i need to do is to unwrap this IO and get a future from it inside the marshaller, i'm just having a bit of trouble with that, i've update the question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you! I managed to make it work with your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work! Thanks to [@luismiguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez) insight, the problem was that the Akka HTTP Marshaller was not able to deal with Cats-Effect IO monad, so the solution was an implementation who unwraps the IO monad using the unsafeToFuture inside the marshaller, that way i was able to keep the Tagless-Final style from point to point, here's the solution:

This implicit fetches the internal marshaller for the type

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller
import cats.effect.IO

trait Marshallable[F[_]]:
  def marshaller[A: ToResponseMarshaller]: ToResponseMarshaller[F[A]]

object Marshallable:
  implicit def marshaller[F[_], A: ToResponseMarshaller](implicit
      M: Marshallable[F]
  ): ToResponseMarshaller[F[A]] = M.marshaller

  given ioMarshallable: Marshallable[IO] with
    def marshaller[A: ToResponseMarshaller] = CatsEffectsMarshallers.ioMarshaller
```

This one unwraps the IO monad and flatMaps the marshaller using a future, which akka-http knows how to deal with.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{
  LowPriorityToResponseMarshallerImplicits,
  Marshaller,
  ToResponseMarshaller
}
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

trait CatsEffectsMarshallers extends LowPriorityToResponseMarshallerImplicits:
  implicit def ioMarshaller[A](implicit
      m: ToResponseMarshaller[A]
  ): ToResponseMarshaller[IO[A]] =
    Marshaller(implicit ec => _.unsafeToFuture().flatMap(m(_)))

object CatsEffectsMarshallers extends CatsEffectsMarshallers
```